# object with ()=>JSX.Elements with typescript

Tags: typescript

We are adding TS support and I have trouble getting the correct type for this object:

```
export const Icons = {
    calendar: () => (
        <path d="m405 427c7 0 12-2 16-6 4-4 6-9 6-16l0-256c0-6-2-11-6-15-4-4-9-6-16-6l-42 0 0-43-64 0 0 43-86 0 0-43-64 0c-7 0-12 2-16 6-4 4-6 9-6 15l0 256c0 7 2 12 6 16 4 4 9 6 16 6z m-21-43l-256 0 0-149 256 0z" />
    ),
    edit: () => (
        <path d="m128 331l0 53 53 0 158 m252-146c5-5 5-14 0-20l-33-33c-6-5-15-5-20 0l-27 26 54 54z" />
    ), 
// ...many more
}
```

I have manged to get it to work with `Record<string, () => JSX.Element>`
But I would like to have the autocomplete for all different icons.

The final component will look something like this:

```
import { Icons } from './Icons';
    type SvgIconProps{
        iconName: string;
        disabled?: boolean;
        dataTest?: string;
    }
    export const SvgIcon = ({  iconName, disabled, dataTest}: SvgIconProps) => {
        const Icon = Icons[iconName];
        return (
            <svg
                {...{
                    disabled,
                    viewBox: '0 0 512 512',
                    'data-test': dataTest || 'svg-icon',
                }}>
                <Icon />
            </svg>
        );
    };
```

I have tried to get the keys like this:

```
type Keys = keyof typeof Icons;
```

Then asign them:

```
iconName: Keys;
```

But this do not give me autocomplete for all different icons we have.

e.g I use this component `<SvgIcon {...{iconName: "auto complete icon name plz"}} />`

This file is really old and we are converting to NextJs.
Maybe there is a better way of writing components like this?

Picture to @Daniel:

[image]

Comment: Do `as const`….

Comment: Sorry but  "as const" on what? 

Comment: You icons object instance

Comment: It only helped every key to become readonly. Added picture to question

Comment: Sorry for being slow on this.. guess this late night is making me even slower than usual 

Comment: Updated the question with small but maybe clearer text :)

Comment: Type inference is your friend. Do nothing and you will end up with a property for each icon. Then when you need to use a generic `export const SvgIcon = <I extends keyof typeof Icons>({ iconName }: { iconName: I }) =>`. If you want the `SvgIconProps` type declaration, you have to make it generic in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Daniel had the correct awnser in the first comment I just needed some sleep to figure out that I still had `Record<string, () => JSX.Element>` on the Icon Object and needed to remove it..